# Using an external Xcode Clang Static Analyzer binary, with additional checks

Tags: xcode, clang-static-analyzer

I’m using Xcode 3.2.4 and have setup the Clang Static Analyser feature to use a newer build of the binary, as detailed here: http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/xcode.html

(Basically using the *set-xcode-analyzer* command line utility to change which copy of the Static Analyser that Xcode uses for *Build and Analyze*.)

What I can’t figure is how to set that binary to use additional checks, such as -analyzer-check-objc-missing-dealloc when using the binary via Xcode, as detailed here: http://loufranco.com/blog/files/scan-build-better-than-build-analyze.html and in scan-build --help.

```
    AVAILABLE ANALYSES (multiple analyses may be specified):

 (+) -analyzer-check-dead-stores
     -analyzer-check-llvm-conventions
 (+) -analyzer-check-objc-mem
 (+) -analyzer-check-objc-methodsigs
     -analyzer-check-objc-missing-dealloc
 (+) -analyzer-check-objc-unused-ivars
 (+) -analyzer-check-security-syntactic

 NOTE: "(+)" indicates that an analysis is enabled by default unless one
       or more analysis options are specified
```

How do you pass in extra options to the binary when used via Xcode?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Upon further investigation, it seems the best way to do this is to use a couple of entries in the Target Build Info, rather than the *set-xcode-analyzer* command line tool.

Add a User-defined setting, *CC*, containing the full path to the newer build of the binary, as follows (note that the */bin/clang* on the end of the path):

```
CC = /Path/To/Folder/With/Clang/checker-244/bin/clang
```

Then in the *Other Warning Flags* entry add as many of the additional checks as you want, as follows:

```
WARNING_CFLAGS = -Xanalyzer -analyzer-check-llvm-conventions -Xanalyzer -analyzer-check-objc-missing-dealloc
```

Each is preceded by the argument *-Xanalyzer* which indicates that the next argument should be passed to the analyzer.

More on this can be found here: [Mac OS X Developer Tools Manual Page](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/clang.1.html).

Then, when you do a *Build and Analyze* in Xcode you should be using the external, newer binary running the additional checks.

Comment: i have done the same thing. my analyzer is working now. but the thing is i m getting an error -lgcc is not found .... what is this ?

Comment: No idea what causes it, but after a lot of futtzing around the following additional config settings seem to work for me, stopping that error appearing:

Comment: RUN_CLANG_STATIC_ANALYZER = NO
GCC_VERSION = com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.analyzer
SDKROOT = iphonesimulator4.1
OTHER_CFLAGS = -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=040100

Comment: I wish you could give you all my karma - easily solved several issues I was having with a...more recent...version of Xcode and scan-build forcing -nodistribute onto it's xcodebuild.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer no longer works (Xcode 4)

The format of Xcode's build file means you have to do it like this:

```
WARNING_CFLAGS = "-Xanalyzer -analyzer-check-llvm-conventions -analyzer-check-objc-missing-dealloc"
```

NB: the quotes surrounding the entire XAnalyzer phrase.